# Creating a game in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, while-loop

I wanted to know how to make a while loop in a game where after the player has played the game once, the user asks them if they would like to play again.If the user enters yes the game restarts but if they say no then the game finishes.

I would like some examples please and if you could use the while true boolean method to explain please as I am having difficulty understanding this.

Comment: I'm afraid SO isn't a site that writes code for you. Have an attempt, and where you hit problems, ask then.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this course [An Introduction to Interactive Programming in Python](https://www.coursera.org/course/interactivepython):

> What is the coolest thing I'll learn if I take this class?
>
> > You’ll be able to build your own games in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your biggest problem is how to use the `while` loop and accepting input within the loop.

Take a look at [While Loops in Python](http://www.khanacademy.org/science/computer-science/v/while-loops-in-python). Will offer basic insight of how it works.

To take a stab at your question, analyze the following code. That should be able to get you started.

```
print "Type 3 to continue, anything else to quit."
someInput = raw_input()

while someInput == '3':
    print "Thank you for the 3. Very kind of you."
    print "Type 3 to continue, anything else to quit."
    someInput = raw_input()

print "That's not 3, so I'm quitting now."
```

Hope this helps.